# Best books for beginners Pot-Limit Omaha

Tags: omaha, books

I am looking for recommendations for the best books for beginners.

I want to learn with a focus on Omaha, however it seems like the books that deal with Omaha are for players who have already studied the basic probabilities, strategy and terms for Texas Holdem.

If that is basically the only option, then I would appreciate a recommendation on the best books for that and the subsequent Omaha books. If there are Omaha focused books that are geared for a beginner in general I would appreciate those.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Best book, I don't know as it's pretty personal opinions, but Master Pot-Limit Omaha the modern aggressive approach by Herbery Okolowitz & Wladimir Taschner is good.

Ok strictly speaking not the most beginner friendly but if you want an excellent book, in my opinion, and are willing to seriously digest the information I'd recommend. You will need to focus and really try your best to take the information in as it can be heavy if you're new to PLO, but you will end up a solid, good PLO player if you do. It's a bit old now, 2014, but unless you're playing with the PLO masters it's still very relevant and very good advice for most games still.

Overall it's a book I recommend to someone who wants to seriously learn PLO.

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely look into it.

Answer (score 1):

I come from finish reading "Pot-Limit Omaha poker. The big play strategy" from Jeff Hwang, and I strongly recomend it for begginers as me playing at low tables.

It show you what hands you should and you shouldn't play preflop.

It covers the main big pot situations and how should you play them to win big pots and to avoid loosing big pots.

The chapter of the straights is extensive and shows you stats about different straight draws you need to know.

[Jeff Hwang: "Pot-limit Omaha Poker: The big play strategy"](https://books.google.es/books?id=IfYn3HrWE4sC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Jeff%20Hwang:%20%22Pot-limit%20Omaha%20Poker:%20The%20big%20play%20strategy%22&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihw4eCgernAhVH-YUKHSosAwMQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=Jeff%20Hwang%3A%20%22Pot-limit%20Omaha%20Poker%3A%20The%20big%20play%20strategy%22&f=false)